# Using two JSON sources for Jekyll output

Tags: json, jekyll

Suppose I have a list of projects (let's call that `proj.json`) and a list of smaller sub-projects (`sub_proj.json`) that are associated with the list of projects. The files are as follows:

**proj.json**

```
[{
            "title": "Project 1",
            "description": "aaa.",
            "subproj": ["RefSP1", "RefSP2"]
        },

        {
            "title": "Project 2",
            "description": "aaa.",
            "subproj": ["RefSP3"]
        }]
```

**sub_proj.json**

```
[{
            "title": "Sub Project 1",
            "description": "aaa.",
            "key": "RefSP1"
        },

        {
            "title": "Sub Project 2",
            "description": "aaa.",
            "key": "RefSP2"
        },

        {
            "title": "Sub Project 3",
            "description": "aaa.",
            "key": "RefSP3"
        }]
```

But in the `output.html`, I seem to be missing something. The code is below: (I removed it of formatting for simplicity)

```
{% for item in site.data.proj %}

{{ item.title }}

{% assign key_array = item.subproj %}

{% for sub in key_array %}
{% assign subproject = site.data.sub_proj | where:"key",sub %}

{{ subproject.title | inspect }}

{% endfor %}
```

I seem to get the correct number of subprojects using `{{ subproject.title | inspect }}`, but they're all `nil`. Adding `jsonify` doesn't really do anything.

edit:

Printing out `{{ item | inspect }}`

results in

```
{ "title"=>"Project 1","description"=>"aaa.","subproj"=>["RefSP1","RefSP2"]}
```

But `{{ subproject | inspect }}`

comes out as

```
[{"title"=>"Sub Project 1","description"=>"aaa.","key"=>"RefSP1"}] [{"title"=>"Sub Project 2","description"=>"aaa.","key"=>"RefSP2"}]
```

The square brackets are the main difference. I tried removing them through filters, still nothing.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by using subproject[0].title, but I'm still not sure why or how it works...

Comment: The `where` filter returns an array of all matching items, it's just in this case it only returns one. You could add a `first` filter afterwards to match the behaviour you expect: `{% assign subproject = site.data.sub_proj | where:"key",sub | first %}`